# How to query google-cloud-datastore to find records that dont have a specific property

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I want to query cloud datastore and find all records that dont have a property 'foo'
I was looking at the docs, but didnt find anything there. 
Any pointers for such query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with a query. You will have to read all records and check if the property exists in each of those entities and do what's needed.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries) states that -

> **Entities lacking a property named in the query are ignored**
>
> Entities of the same kind need not have the same properties. To be
>   eligible as a query result, an entity must possess a value (possibly
>   null) for every property named in the query's filters and sort orders.
>   If not, the entity is omitted from the indexes used to execute the
>   query and consequently will not be included in the query's results.
>
> **Note:** It is not possible to query for entities that are specifically
>   lacking a given property. One alternative is to add the property with
>   a null value, then filter for entities with null as the value of that
>   property.